# Create string ndarray from ndarray of int 'flags' using list of string meanings

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, mapping

I'm trying to go from an `ndarray` of integer 'flags':

```
array([[1, 3, 2],
       [2, 0, 3],
       [3, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 1]])
```

to an `ndarray` of strings:

```
array([['Banana', 'Celery', 'Carrot'],
       ['Carrot', 'Apple', 'Celery'],
       ['Celery', 'Carrot', 'Apple'],
       ['Carrot', 'Apple', 'Banana']],
      dtype='|S6')
```

Using a list of strings as the mapping of 'flags' to 'meanings':

```
meanings = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot', 'Celery']
```

I've come up with the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> meanings = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot', 'Celery']
>>> flags = np.array([[1,3,2],[2,0,3],[3,2,0],[2,0,1]])
>>> flags
array([[1, 3, 2],
       [2, 0, 3],
       [3, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 1]])
>>> mapped = np.array([meanings[f] for f in flags.flatten()]).reshape(flags.shape)
>>> mapped
array([['Banana', 'Celery', 'Carrot'],
       ['Carrot', 'Apple', 'Celery'],
       ['Celery', 'Carrot', 'Apple'],
       ['Carrot', 'Apple', 'Banana']],
      dtype='|S6')
```

This works, but I'm concerned about the efficiency (list comp, `flatten`, `reshape`) of the pertinent line when dealing with large `ndarrays`:

```
np.array([meanings[f] for f in flags.flatten()]).reshape(flags.shape)
```

Is there a better/more efficient way of performing a mapping like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fancy indexing is the *numpythonic* way of doing it:

```
mapped = meanings[flags]
```

or the often faster equivalent:

```
mapped = np.take(meanings, flags)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jamie. One note though, only the second solution using `np.take` works with `ndims > 1`.  For my example, the first solution results in: `TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index`

Comment: That's because `meanings` is a list. If you convert it to an ndarray (i.e. `meanings = np.array(meanings)`) then both methods will work equally well.

Answer (score 2):

I think `np.vectorize` is the way to go, it's also really clear and easy to follow. I haven't tested the following but it should work.

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(lambda x : meanings[x])

mapped = vfunc(flags)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm - though you have a typo: `mapped = vfunc(flags)`

Comment: `np.vectorize` is a Python loop in disguise, plus you are making a Python call per array item. It allows for cleaner looking code, but it gives the falseimpression that you are going to get numpy performance, which you are not.

Comment: For the longest time I was under the impression that `np.vectorize` was written in Cython and compiled which gave it that edge in performance but Jamie's right it's [pure python](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.7.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1704).